# Specify specific amount of line breaks in JSCS or ESLint

Tags: javascript, eslint, jscs

JSCS has a `disallowMultipleLineBreaks` rule. This asserts that there is no more than 1 line break between statements in JavaScript. I would like to allow 2 line breaks between method declarations, but no more than 2. I'd also like to disallow more than 1 line break between statements that are *not* method declarations. An example:

```
module.exports = {
  foo : function () { },


  // ok
  bar : function () {},

  baz : function () {
    const QUX = 'QUX'


    // not ok
  }
}
```

Is this possible in either ESLint or JSCS?

Comment: Here is the appropriate rule from eslint: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines .... But its very generic and not very specific like you want.

Comment: @Gyandeep That's at least better than what I have been using. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the appropriate rule from `ESLint`: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines ....

But its very generic and not very specific like you want.